# Image quality of PSD-originating JPG images degrades and changes significantly when uploading images online

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I really hope someone can help! In the past few months I have been having issues with the colors on my jpg files, originating from Photoshop (not sure if this has anything to do with it). When uploading the images online, the colors and contrast are majorly affected. Please see the attached image 1,  versus the image that was uploaded onto smugmug AND email. As soon as the image is uploaded, the colors go wack!  However, if I *download* the image from email or smugmug, it looks like the original. It appears that it is just the web presentation that is affected. This is problematic for me, as I am a photographer and need my images to look like the originals when they are posted online. In my most recent blog post: http://www.heathertufts.com/blog/wedding-bells-at-the-doctors-house/ the featured image (from the wordpress account), is green and contrasty. The original is a soft B&W. I just don't get it!!!  help? :)

[image: image1][image]

Comment: For web, I usually resize the images to 1500X1500 (approx) pixels/inch. (down from like 5000 x5000) So, this terrible affect on my photos is happening on Smugmug (where i upload my photos for clients to see), on my website (wordpress) AND through email!! It is only the files originating from PS. If I take a screen shot of the image as I see it- before it becomes distorted, and then save it as a jpg, the colors don't change.

Comment: Also- in my most recent blog post- ALL Of the images in that gallery are contrasty and nothing like the originals :(

Comment: Files are being saved in "Embed color profile: Adobe RGB (1998)"    Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is most likely the color profile that you are using.

Adobe RGB uses a wider gamut than sRGB - specifically in the cyan-green range.

sRGB is design for best color reproduction on the widest amount of standard monitors so will give you a better result.

When saving your images you should use 'Save for Web & Devices' and be sure that the color profile you are using is sRGB (in Photoshop CS5 this is a tick box labeled 'Convert to sRGB').

A google search for 'adobe rgb 1998 vs srgb' should give you plenty more info on this.

Some more background info (from [www.cambridgeincolour.com](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/sRGB-AdobeRGB1998.htm)):

> sRGB is a RGB color space proposed by HP and Microsoft because it
>   approximates the color gamut of the most common computer display
>   devices. Since sRGB serves as a "best guess" for how another person's
>   monitor produces color, it has become the standard color space for
>   displaying images on the internet. sRGB's color gamut encompasses just
>   35% of the visible colors specified by CIE. Although sRGB results in
>   one of the narrowest gamuts of any working space, sRGB's gamut is
>   still considered broad enough for most color applications.
>
> Adobe RGB 1998 was designed (by Adobe Systems, Inc.) to encompass most
>   of the colors achievable on CMYK printers, but by using only RGB
>   primary colors on a device such as your computer display. The Adobe
>   RGB 1998 space encompasses roughly 50% of the visible colors specified
>   by CIE — improving upon sRGB's gamut primarily in cyan-greens.

Comment: This seems like really great information! Let me test it out. Thank you so much! (I will keep you updated)